# QGIS Processing Plugin Not Loading "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp"

Tags: qgis, error, qgis-processing

I am having serious issues with my QGIS program regarding the Processing Plugin. Upon start-up and if I turn on the plugin within the program.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the program. Have wiped it clean from the computer, and continue to have this error come up.

It appeared all of a sudden when I opened the program at the beginning of the day.

[image]
[[image: ][2]]

Comment: Please post the whole error message. Particularly the most relevant last lines.

Comment: Hi @underdark thanks for the comment. I added the last part of the error message

Answer (score 1):

I remember that I tried to change the directory for r-scipts in QGIS. I changed it into a location on an external hard drive. I ran QGIS without the hard drive linked to my PC and QGIS produced the same error like yours, Zach. After connecting the hard drive again, QGIS produced no error while starting and I could change the directory to the old path again: ....qgis2\processing\rscripts. You could try the same.

Answer (score 0):

Something about the configured R scripts folder seems off. Do you remember changing anything related to that. It's probably best to open a ticket for this issue.